# How to %cd to a path containing env variable in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am setting a project path to some env variable like PROJECT_HOME by us using os.environ like this:

`os.environ['PROJECT_HOME'] = os.getcwd()`

so I can use `%cd $PROJECT_HOME/abc/xyz` in later cell

However, the system return this:

`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '${PROJECT_HOME}/abc/xyz'`

Is there a way to use env variable in %cd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me: `%cd {os.environ['PROJECT_HOME']}`

Comment: It just gives me: [ERRNO 2] No such file or directory: '{os.environ[PROJECT_HOME]}'

Answer (score 2):

I just realized the magic `%cd` could access python variable. Therefore it could be done like this:

```py
import os
PROJECT_HOME = os.getcwd()

%cd {PROJECT_HOME}
```

Having said that, the answer by [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8821969/daniel-schneider) is the right answer to the question because I asked how to `%cd` a path containing an environment variable.